# Мониторинг файловой системы с помощью python

Tags: python, docker

Делаю проект - динамический анализ в docker контейнере с ubuntu в качестве основы. Решил анализировать файловую систему на изменения и сохранять данные логи в текстовый документ через volume на хоствовую машину. Сам скрипт запускается аналогично с хоста. Перепробовал библиотеки по типу inotify, watchdog и другие. Решил остановится на подобном [коде](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15071134/21239983). Момент с files можно заменить на [os.path.join(dp, f) for dp, dn, fn in os.walk(os.path.expanduser("/")) for f in fn]. Но часто происходят ошибки из-за удаления некоторых файлов или папок: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/bin/pack200'. Подскажите, как можно отслежить похожим образом изменения в системе и логировать это.

Comment: auditd  взрослые дяди делают, а не это баловство